# How to create the vertical line [Pipe]

Tags: command-line, grep, pipe

I am new to Ubuntu and i want to know how to create the vertical line that's Pipe in ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Which locale keyboard do you have ?

Comment: Presumably locale independent: [Ctrl-Shift-u 7 c](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash).

Answer (score 1):

on most english locale keyboard:

Locate a button that looks like this(as shown below):
[image: keyboard]

then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: Depending on the locate of the keyboard it might not be <kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: @NGRhodes ill change my answer(which may be what he wants) asap gives us locale