# How to search greek alphabets?

Tags: unity-previews

I want to insert greek alphabets like theta, beta etc.   How i can do it???
I am trying to make a word file just in Microsoft word. I have drawn table but can't find different greek and roman alphabets.

Comment: Microsoft Word does not run natively in Ubuntu... are you using Ubuntu? Or any Linux even?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I type a unicode character (for example, em-dash —?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a few Greek letters (e. g. as formula or unit symbols), you can

- open *Character Map*¹ and choose *Greek* as the letter system or Unicode block, or
- in LibreOffice and OpenOffice Writer select *Insert > Special Characters* from the main menu and choose *Basic Greek* in the drop down menu. I remember a similar function in Microsoft Word.

Both offer a grid of symbols and glyphs of the Greek alphabet that you can copy and/or insert.

¹ The executable is called `gucharmap` for the GNOME desktop.

Comment: If someone knows the equivalent, default character map applications of KDE, LXDE, or Xfce, feel free to edit my answer.