# How to write en and em dashes?

Tags: gnome, customization, configure, character-set

I understand that to be able to type en and em dashes I have to configure the <kbd>COMPOSE</kbd> key, or something like that, but I am not sure about that nor on how I get from there to be able to type en and em dashes in addition to the minus sign.

How do I type en and em dashes on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18?

I have now looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/31283/364819), so I would now also like to know the code for the en dash and how to assign other keyboard shortcuts to these Unicode characters, as I don't want to have to type something too long in order to get these.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I type a unicode character (for example, em-dash —?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash)

Comment: Gosh, I just wrote the same thing in an answer. :D

Comment: Eh, search the character map?

Comment: Also, did you see http://askubuntu.com/a/585133/158442?

Comment: The em-dash `—`... [has its own, direct shortcut. `alt`-`-`, at least under Ubuntu-MATE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash/585133#comment2001135_31258)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to learn the Unicode numbers of these two characters. They are not actually hard to remember, because they look like years. ;)

- En dash: `U+2013`
- Em dash: `U+2014`

To write a Unicode symbol, perform the following actions:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (the display will show something like **u̲**)
- Type the code (e.g. `2014`)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There you go: – —

For a complete reference to Unicode characters, run `gucharmap`.

Comment: I prefer @cipricus's answer below, using the 'compose' key, because those mnemonically chosen 2 or 3 character sequences are easier to remember than arbitrary four digit hex numbers, especially if one uses the same mechanism for other unicode characters as well.

Comment: Given the solution involves pressing Ctrl-Shift-u, then typing 2013 or 2014, then pressing Enter — what does the first part of the answer (`U+2013` etc) mean?

Comment: @JonathanHartley I am not sure if you are the one who downvoted the answer, but it was not necessary. My answer provides a method which is working, therefore it is correct. If you prefer someone else's answer of course you should upvote theirs.

Comment: @cipricus that's the Unicode notation for symbols.

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto You are right that my downvote is inappropriate. I reviewed the guidelines for "when to downvote" https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-down and they are exactly as you describe. A downvote should only be for answers that are not useful, not ones that are judged inferior to other answers. I will undo my downvote if I can (ie. if the question is edited.)

Comment: @JonathanHartley - I put my up-vote too (at least to compensate).

Comment: @JonathanHartley no worries. I prefer when people who downvote do leave some kind of reasoning. You left a comment and that is appreciated.

Comment: @cipricus I upvoted yours as well, you made me learn something new after years of using Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Compose key can be used like this: ­

- `Compose` and then `--.` gives `–` (en-dash).
- `Compose` and then `---` gives `—` (em-dash).

The compose key can be set in the advanced [keyboard settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/70784/925128)

In LibreOffice Writer one can use `:--:` and `:---:`.

In LO there is also the method of using the LO auto-corrector and set `--` to `–` and `---` to `—` for example (but this has the limitation that the automatic corrector acts only after the end of a "word", that is, after Space is pressed, so that, in order to put the em dash close to a word —the way it's often done in English—, you have to delete that space manually etc).

— The compose solution seems the best, as it works everywhere, including in a browser and a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

When I look up "em dash" on the gnome 3 overview a result comes up that puts it on the clipboard. I think you need to have gnome-characters installed for it to work.