# Can't type "|" (vertical pipe)

Tags: command-line, keyboard, lubuntu

I can't type `|`. I have tried to press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press and release <kbd>U</kbd> and then type [`007c`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes) but nothing happens.

I do not know if I make the wrong sequence of pressing and holding. I get crazy! I am trying to enter the command:

```
sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This is for my pinball 2000 running on Lubuntu/pinbox.

I selected Sweden and Swedish keyboard in the installation.

Comment: Copy and paste from another site? e.g. http://www.linfo.org/vertical_bar_character.html

Comment: Which language / keyboard are you using? The key / key combination for the pipe character depends strongly on the language / keyboard.

Comment: I selected Sweden and Swedish keyboard in the installation. I can try to reinstall with all american settings!?

Comment: Press the `Alt Gr` key and and after that the key between `z` and `shift` to get `|` in a Swedish keyboard. (This key has `<` , `>` and `|` in a Swedish keyboard.)

Comment: Thank you!!! I thought that that was another symbol. It looks more like a long ":" meaning it is a gap in between/not a compete line like "|" when i type it in lubutu.

Comment: Is it suppose to look like the long ":" in Lubutu?

Comment: In some fonts the pipe character looks like two vertical bars with a small space between. (I guess that is what you mean. I think in most fonts it is one solid vertical bar, but I have seen it as two vertical bars with a small space between, and that is what it looks like on the key of some keyboards.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66459/discussion-between-sudodus-and-anders).

Comment: @Anders, You are welcome :-)

Comment: By the way, pasting in a terminal works with either Ctrl+Shift+V or by selecting the text to paste and pressing the middle mouse button where it should be pasted. Especially the last one is great for fast copying oneliners like yours.

Comment: **on my keyboard shift+\ makes |**

Answer (score 24):

### Key combination to type the pipe character in a Swedish keyboard

Press the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key and and after that the key between <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> to get <kbd>|</kbd> in a Swedish keyboard. (This key has <kbd><</kbd> (default), <kbd>></kbd> (with <kbd>shift</kbd>) and <kbd>|</kbd> (with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) in a Swedish keyboard.)

I think in most fonts the pipe character is one solid vertical bar, but I have seen it as two vertical bars with a small space between, and that is what it looks like on the key of some keyboards, like the picture in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkNZR.jpg).

### `onboard` helps explore keys and key combinations

[image]

You can install **`onboard`** and use it to explore which keys and key combinations to use to type various letters, digits and symbols in different languages.

Comment: Worked on an Acer running CentOs on VirtualBox: AltGr + the `~` (left to number 1).

Answer (score 4):

I tried to do exactly as you tried, Anders. My keyboard is Brazilian (ABNT), so I have similar keyboard peculiarities and annoyances, as signals and accents, too.

According [to this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash?rq=1) issue, I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the same sequence you tried to do, to make it work.

I think if you repeat the sequence you tried at your question, finally press<kbd>Enter</kbd> (*), it will works!

PS: Don`t forget to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> after press <kbd>U</kbd>.

(*)<kbd>space</kbd> works,too.

Comment: The second sentence of the question is exactly this.

Comment: @muru, I edited my answer. See if it's suitable, now.

Comment: You don't need to press Enter specifically - Spacebar would do too.

Comment: Exactly @muru, It worked. I tested any other key, none of them worked. Do you know anyelse?

Comment: Tapping Shift or Ctrl as well (not holding, since capital A-E are valid characters here). Tapping Super or Alt cancels.

Comment: Ok, it worked, but these commands are more complicated. Let it be just as I answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. With a Ducky 65% keyboard the button Ubuntu assigned to vertical pipe wasn't physically existent. I ended up adding a cronjob on boot that uses `xmodmap` to set vertbar to keyboards altgr+6. This is the command:
`xmodmap -e "keycode 15 = 6 ampersand 6 asciicircum bar fiveeighths"`

Answer (score 1):

I found this symbol by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>#</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot follow your problem. I just changed my German keyboard for the purpose of trying to understand your problem by typing `setxkbmap se` on the command line, and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd> got  the same result as when using `setxkbmap de`.

Comment: There's no key `|` at least on my keyboard, you probably mean the `<` key.

Comment: Just checked  this link for Swedish layout ; https://documentation.vizrt.com/viz-easycut-guide/4.12/vizeasycut_usersguide_swedish_keyboard_layout.html and it shows  the third level select key (AltGr) just like my German KB. Is yours somehow non-standard?

Comment: Well, on some keyboards, several symbols are printed on the keys, for example this one, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkNZR.jpg, so you could say `|` key (not only `<` key, @dessert).

Comment: @DavidWalker, there was confusion because the symbol on the OPs key was not a solid vertical bar, but two vertical bars with a small space between, which "looks like a long `:` ". We solved that issue via comments.