# Custom keyboard shortcut to print symbol

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to set a custom shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> [that's a hyphen] to print an em dash and can't get the right command. `echo —` doesn't work.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

[xdotool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181488/simulating-key-press-using-bash) -> link where i found how the tool should work
This program will work only on a xorg system.
`sudo apt install xdotool` and then when creating a shortcut,
set the command as `xdotool key -`. This should simulate the key press.
Note that i didn't try this program so i don't know if it works, please comment below if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I found another way to achieve it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash#31283

Comment: For the record, I tried it just now and it didn't work. It seems like `xdotool` needs the specified key to be an actual keyboard key. Letters and numbers worked, but symbols, even simple ones like `*` didn't.