# Add a custom shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, customization

So basically, I'd like to do what's written in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/31265/929735) from 2011 but for Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd like to type an Em-dash from anywhere in my Ubuntu. 
When I do:

1. **Settings > Devices > Keyboards**
2. then I go all the way down and click **+** to add a custom shortcut
3. I name it for instance **Em dash**
4. enter --. for the command and set the shortcut to `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `6`

The shortcut doesn't seem to work in anyapp (Atom, Firefox, Terminal etc.). I tried other shortcuts like `AltGr` + `Shift` + `6` and I also restarted my computer to see if it'd work. It doesn't. Am I missing something?