# Activating the Keyboard Compose Key in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: compose-key

I followed the steps in Settings - Keyboard - Compose Key and switched off the Default in the pop-up menu; then selected **left-Alt** as the **Compose key**; then followed the steps mentioned at the top of the same pop-up menu.  But it did not work when I tried composing a special character with a diacritic...  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude laptop with a US keyboard layout format.

Answer (score 4):

Left alt doesn't seem to work at all as the compose key on 22.04, which is ironic seeing as how it's the default. I've found the other options work though.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. Apparently a bug, and [I reported it](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/2509).

Comment: Can confirm - Ubuntu 22.04, default settings didn't work, switching off "layout default" but leaving Left Alt selected also didn't work, but switching it to Caps Lock did.

Answer (score 1):

I was flummoxed by this, but I was able to explicitly set the Compose Key <kbd>right alt</kbd> and that does work. <kbd>left alt</kbd> did not work at all. In my initial testing it seemed like neither worked, but I can't reproduce that.

With compose set to <kbd>right alt</kbd>:

- <kbd>rt alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd> gives me ½,
- <kbd>rt alt</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> gives me é.

The setting is in the keyboard settings:
[image]